# Is the stack area of process memory a fixed size?

Tags: memory, operating-system, stack

In the stack area, "fixed size" and "non-fixed size" are confused. This is because in the operating-system-concepts-10th book, **"the stack and heap sections can shrink and grow dynamically draw program execution"**, but in other articles comparing the stack area and the heap area, **the stack area is referred to as a fixed size.**
Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.